# How to change context in testing android hybrid app

Tags: android, protractor, appium, appium-android

I'm trying to test a hybrid app using appium and protractor. If I run my test in android+chrome with simple `browser.get()`. The protractor test works, but when running in app it shows an error:[image]

Appium logs shows that it has 2 available context, [image]but when I try to set the context to webview using `driver.context('WEBVIEW_com.google.android.gms')` it doesn't work.

I've been googling for days already but none seems to work for me. TIA!

Comment: Does your Android app have setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled flag set to true?

Comment: @Angusiasty not sure really, I am just  trying out sample APKs from a sites. That is really matter? I have tried only 2 apps though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to switch to the webview:

```
public void switchToWebview() {
    Set<String> availableContexts = driver.getContextHandles();
    for (String context : availableContexts) {
        if (context.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
            System.out.println("Context Name is " + context);
            driver.context(context);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works fine for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I am using protractorJS. tried driver.context() but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can give Appium Studio a try. You can find [here](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Setting+Context) on how to switch context in AppiumStudio. Its a easy to use tool with integrations with various other frameworks